# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT with ORDER BY returning results in the wrong order

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that stores product information which includes the fields: id(unique), ean, price.

I am trying to group all results with the same ean number, and then order by price.  I am using GROUP_CONCAT because some ean records are NULL.  I am using the following query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), * FROM table GROUP BY ean ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 500
```

The results returned are not ordered by price ascending.  I have tried adding  ORDER BY into the GROUP_CONCAT, however this is returning a MySQL error:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY price ASC), * FROM table GROUP BY ean LIMIT 500
```

Syntax error or access violation

Comment: Order by _which_ price?  A given `ean` value might have multiple records, each of which can have a different price.

Comment: The lowest price

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is not a good practice, that raises error in versions of MySQL where `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is enabled (which is default since version 5.7).

Same goes for `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`: which result will appear in the resultset cannot be told consistantly.

You *maybe* want:

```
SELECT ean, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY price ASC) ids
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY ean
ORDER BY ean
LIMIT 500
```

Or:

```
SELECT ean, GROUP_CONCAT(id) ids
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY ean
ORDER BY MIN(price)
LIMIT 500
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this option:

```
SELECT ean, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ean
ORDER BY MIN(price)
LIMIT 500
```

This orders each `ean` group by the smallest price among all records.

Answer (score 0):

One important characteristic of `GROUP_CONCAT` function is, that the `ORDER BY` clause allows you to sort the values in ascending or descending order before concatenating.

**By default**, it sorts the values in ascending order. If you want to sort the values in the descending order, you need to specify explicitly the `DESC` option.

Also `GROUP_CONCAT` function **ignores** `NULL` values. so if it happens that there are items without a price in your case, it will return `NULL` if there was no matching row found or all arguments are `NULL` values.

**Another important thing:** the default characters length `GROUP_CONCAT` is 1024.

If 1024 characters length is fine for you requirement then there is nothing to worry. But if not, you have to modify the `GROUP_CONCAT` character length as per your requirement as below:

```
  SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```